# AWS AppSync not returning all the records from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

While using DynamoDB as a data source, I show a total record count of 135 rows of sample data. When I am running a `listAll` query, however, I see very random data on the screen limited to 20 records.

When I investigated by adding the `limit` argument set to 150, I am getting all of the data. If I keep the limit to two or three and try to add a filter to query the results, I am not getting *any*.

When I went on to check the Request Mapping template, I found the default value for limit is being passed as twenty. Hence we see random twenty records.

```
"limit": $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.limit, 20)
```

So, if your filter has the record details of any of these twenty records, you will get the result. If there’s anything else in DynamoDB, it won't be returned.

If you remove this limit attribute from the RequestMappingTemplate, you are greeted with all the data. But then, anytime you pass the limit it will not be accounted for, and you will get all of the results.

What I see from this exercise is the limit is directly associated with something like row index.

The reason I say this: Let’s suppose you are running the query with a filter, and you are not getting any results, but a `nextToken` is available.
If you query again with this `nextToken`, with a limit of say two, you won't be getting any results again if these records you are looking for don’t fall under the twenty records which the query retrieves.

In other words, it appears to first fetch the `limit` and only *then* applies the filter.

I also checked the same in the DynamoDB, I am not having any such issues while filtering.

Can anyone help me with this? I have been through other similar posts here, but they don’t address the scenario where the `limit` restricts the query pool, instead of the number of returned results.

Answer (score 1):

When you query or scan a DynamoDB table, you can limit the number of items that are returned. Any filtering is done after the limit though, which can give you pages of “no data” before finding the items you are looking for, just as you’ve described.

Note that although you can remove the limit, DynamoDB will still enforce a maximum page of 1MB. The number of items will depend on how big your items are. So unless you will always have <1MB of data in your table, you will need to implement pagination at the front end otherwise your query will not check all items once the page size (the number of items) is too large.

If you want a more consistent number of results per page after filtering, you probably want to query an index rather than filter. You can try adding a GSI so that you can query just those items that you’re looking for. This will make your query more efficient and will give your frontend a more consistent item count in each page response.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ben,
finally I was able to retrieve the results using GSI post changing the request mapping template as below:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "index" : "brand-index",
    "query" : {
        "expression": "#brand = :brand",
        "expressionNames" : {
            "#brand" : "brand"
        },
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":brand" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.brand)    
        }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "expression" : "contains(#type, :type)",
        "expressionNames" : {
            "#type" : "type"
        },
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":type" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.type)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was due to misunderstanding Hash as comment and removed it earlier(#brand). Also I noticed that we cannot use Primary Key in filter, and also the sort key.

Thanks 
Shahid Nawaz